# Lodash filtering to return object rather than array with 1 length

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I'm using this code to filter an array:

```
var filteredValues = _.filter(arrayOfObjects, function(obj) {
    return obj.id === id;
});
```

Here's how I'm trying to get the first result:

```
console.log('id', filteredValues[0].id);
```

I know how to use chaining but I forgot which lodash function I can use so that the first object found will be assigned to `filteredValues`.

I can use the code below but it looks too elementary. I want a full lodash solution.

```
var cleanedfilteredValues = {};
cleanedfilteredValues = filteredValues[0];
```

Comment: [`_.find`](https://lodash.com/docs#find)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using a strict equality operator to compare collection item property values, you can use pass an object to `find()`, making your code even smaller:

```
var filteredValues = _.find(arrayOfObjects, { id: id });
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Amadan, this is the code I'm using now

```
var filteredValues = _.find(arrayOfObjects, function(obj) {
    return obj.id === id;
});
```

Thanks!